# How can I configure maven to use a repository based on the folder the project is in or in the dependency coordinates?

Tags: maven

I work for a company in which I have to use VPN to access its resources, including its artifact repository (artifactory). In order to access this repository, I configured a settings.xml in my `/.m2` directory.

Nevertheless, I do not want to use this settings when I do my open source projects in my free time for multiple reasons (main one being not use the VPN).

My work-related projects and personal projects are in different directories.

I cannot add the repository manually in the pom files, because all other devs have it in their `.m2` directory and do not care about using it always (and because there are a lot of projects).

Is is possible to:

- use one settings.xml file per folder?
- configure in the settings.xml file to only get given artifacts (based on the dependency coordinates, for instance starting with com.acme, for instance) from my company's repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can have different `settings.xml`. To choose a non-standard one, you need to specify it on the command line with `-s other-settings.xml`.

Alternatively, you can use different users, because you can have one standard `settings.xml` per user.

Comment: By user you mean operating system user?

Comment: Yes, operating system user.